# Evaluating mediator effect, through SEM model selection with AIC

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, mediation, lavaan, sentiment-analysis

I am new to SEM and the `lavaan` R package, so perhaps this is a basic question.

I have social media data with three variables:

- `s0` - subject sentiment on **day 0**
- `n1` - whether subject was exposed to a natural area on **day 1**
- `s2` - subject sentiment on **day 2**

Each row in the dataset represents a particular 3-day sequence for a particular subject.

To make this post reproducible, a subset of the data is available on Dropbox and can be imported into R as follows -

```r
url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/2g82xraogjwal8o/sample_subset.csv?dl=1"
dat = read.csv(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(dat)
```

Here is how the first few rows appear in R -

```
##   user_id       s0    n1       s2
## 1       1 6.377143 FALSE 0.000000
## 2       1 5.728750 FALSE 0.000000
## 3       1 0.000000 FALSE 0.000000
## 4       1 0.000000 FALSE 6.360000
## 5       1 0.000000 FALSE 2.282222
## 6       1 6.360000 FALSE 0.000000
```

The question I'm trying to evaluate is whether exposure to nature is acting as a mediator to improve sentiment. Namely, the hypothesis is that subjects with *low* sentiment on **day 0** will tent to seek exposure to nature on **day 1**, and subsequently will have *higher* sentiment on **day 2**.

To evaluate this, I constructed four SEM models, acting as alternative hypotheses, in `lavaan`:

```r
library(lavaan)

fit0 = sem("s2 ~ 1", dat)

fit1 = sem("s2 ~ n1 
           n1 ~ s0", dat)

fit2 = sem("s2 ~ s0", dat)

fit3 = sem("s2 ~ n1 
           n1 ~ s0 
           s2 ~ s0", dat)
```

Here is a brief summary of the models:

- `fit0` - null model (intercept-only)
- `fit1` - sentiment on day 2 is affected by sentiment on day 0, through mediation of exposure to nature on day 1
- `fit2` - sentiment on day 2 is affected by sentiment on day 0 (directly)
- `fit3` - sentiment on day 2 is affected by sentiment on day 0, both directly *and* through mediation of exposure to nature on day 1

Next, I compared the AIC of the four models -

```r
tmp = data.frame(
  model = paste0("fit", 0:3),
  aic = c(AIC(fit0), AIC(fit1), AIC(fit2), AIC(fit3)), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

According to the result, `fit2` (direct effect only) is the most parsimonious model -

```r
tmp = tmp[order(tmp$aic), ]
tmp
```

```
##   model      aic
## 3  fit2 5268.465
## 1  fit0 5414.705
## 4  fit3 5576.244
## 2  fit1 5679.925
```

The following image is a visualization of the four models (using `semPaths`), with the "chosen" model (`fit2`) marked in red -

[image: Four SEM models]

My **conclusion** is:

*Sentiment on day 2 is directly affected by sentiment on day 0, and the mediating effect of exposure to mature is not substantial.*

And the **question** is:

*Whether this analysis is reasonable, or did I miss anything important in terms of methodology?*

Any help is appreciated, thank you very much!

---

**Edit:**

Following @Noah's suggestion referring to [this](http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/mediation.html) tutorial, the following is a formal test of mediation effect -

```r
# Formal test of mediation
model <- ' # direct effect
             s2 ~ c*s0
           # mediator
             n1 ~ a*s0
             s2 ~ b*n1
           # indirect effect (a*b)
             ab := a*b
           # total effect
             total := c + (a*b)
         '
fit3 = sem(model, dat, se = "bootstrap", bootstrap = 10000)
```

Which gives this result -

```r
summary(fit3)
```

```
## lavaan 0.6-3 ended normally after 27 iterations
## 
##   Optimization method                           NLMINB
##   Number of free parameters                          5
## 
##   Number of observations                          1001
## 
##   Estimator                                         ML
##   Model Fit Test Statistic                       0.000
##   Degrees of freedom                                 0
##   Minimum Function Value               0.0000000000000
## 
## Parameter Estimates:
## 
##   Standard Errors                            Bootstrap
##   Number of requested bootstrap draws            10000
##   Number of successful bootstrap draws            9989
## 
## Regressions:
##                    Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
##   s2 ~                                                
##     s0         (c)    0.282    0.046    6.149    0.000
##   n1 ~                                                
##     s0         (a)    0.021    0.004    5.490    0.000
##   s2 ~                                                
##     n1         (b)    2.155    0.540    3.994    0.000
## 
## Variances:
##                    Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
##    .s2               10.880    1.150    9.459    0.000
##    .n1                0.082    0.007   11.748    0.000
## 
## Defined Parameters:
##                    Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
##     ab                0.045    0.014    3.259    0.001
##     total             0.327    0.047    7.017    0.000
```

The `ab` effect is significant (p=0.001), therefore the conclusion is that the mediation effect is significant.

Comment: AIC gives an indication of the relative fit of the models in the sample, but the question of whether there is mediation is a population question and warrants a formal hypothesis test. What the link above demonstrates is that the direct effect-only model actually sets two parameters to 0, while a test for mediation only requires one of those parameters to be 0.

Comment: @Noah Thanks! two questions: (1) AIC already encompasses model complexity (number of estimated parameters), so if the model without mediation has lower AIC than the model with mediation, can't it be considered as a formal test of mediation effect? (2) if the answer is "no", then could you please suggest an alternative formal test of mediation? Sorry if this is a trivial question but I'm new to this...

Comment: The AIC is not a formal test. It's a summary statistic, and comparing two summary statistics doesn't tell you whether a model will fit better in the population. It only tells you whether the fit/complexity trade-off works better in this sample. There is one formal test for mediation: whether product of the coefficients in `s2 ~ n1` and `n1 ~ s0` is different from zero. See [here](http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/mediation.html) for a tutorial in `lavaan`. Make sure you use bootstrapping to compute the standard errors (which is available as an option in `lavaan`).

Comment: @Noah Thank you very much for the clarification! I edited the question to include a formal test of mediation effect. In case you have time to take a look and confirm that I got it right, will greatly appreciate it.